# Custom title validation on ruby on rails >= 4

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

Let's say I have the following:

class: **Form**, fields: [name], *has_many*: **custom_fields**

class: **CustomField**, fields: [name, required], *belongs_to*: **form**, *has_many*: **answers**

class **Answer**, fields: [typed_value], *belongs_to*: **form**, **custom_field**

and the records:

```
Form(id: 1, name: 'Le form')

CustomField(id: 1, form_id: 1, name: "What's your favorite food", required: true)

CustomField(id: 2, form_id: 1, name: "What's your favorite color", required: true)

CustomField(id: 3, form_id: 1, name: "Some other question", required: false)
```

And I'm trying to create one answer to each question with and empty 'typed_value' (type_value == ''), how do I produce the messages: ["What's your favorite food must be present", "What's your favorite color must be present"] in the 'Rails way'? Without manually setting the entire text in the errors.messages Hash?

Something like:

(*class* **Answer**)

```
validates :typed_value, presence: true, if: :method_that_returns_custom_field_required_attr, custom_title: :error_title

def error_title(title)
  return custom_field.name if title == :typed_value
  title
end

# and not like

validate :required_error, if: :method_that_returns_custom_field_required_attr

def required_error
  if typed_value.empty?
    errors.add(:somewhere_base_probably, I18.t('must be present', le_title: custom_field.name))
  end
end
```

**Obs**: Not only *presence* but *min*, *max*, *only_integer* etc...